# Oracle APEX Interactive grid, when changing month in date picker column, it goes to bottom of page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

So I had a large Interactive Grid in APEX 18.2, it had quite a few rows, and when I went to edit one of the dates, it opened up the date picker popup, and I wanted it to be in a different month, so I go to the next month, and I get teleported to the bottom of the page, which for a large table is quite a ways scrolling.

I solved the problem myself but wrote here just in case someone else stumbles upon it.

Comment: So this is dumb, I posted the question and the answer as I had solved this before posting, but it wont let me accept my own answer for two days.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, I had some columns that I wanted to be read-only, so I had set them to Read Only, condition: Always, execute: Once.
Well here is where the problem arises from, the Once for some reason throws you to the bottom of the page, when I set the execute: For Each Row, it worked just fine.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if it's for some reason intentional and I just didn't know, but well, it is how it is.